# About min and max functions working with lists

Tags: python, list, sum, max, min

I'm trying to print min() and max() values from a list generated from list()

```
x = [list(range(1,11))]
print(min(x))
print(max(x))
```

That returns the raw list twice: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
But when i write

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print(min(x))
print(max(x))
```

It returns the actual min and max values: 1 and 10

What am i missing?

Comment: ```x = [list(range(1, 11))]``` is a list, within a list in your first example. try ```x = list(range(1,11))```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = [list(range(1,11))]
```

is making a `list` of `list`s; the `list` constructor converts the `range` to a `list`, and the square brackets then declare another `list` that contains that `list`. It's like doing:

```
x = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]  # Note two brackets on each side
```

Obviously, the `max` and `min` of a `list` with only one element (the inner list) will be that single element. It's the everything-est of elements in that `list`. If you want it equivalent to:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

just do:

```
x = list(range(1,11))  # No brackets needed; the list constructor makes a single unnested list
```

or if you really like the bracket syntax, you can use generalized unpacking like so:

```
x = [*range(1,11)]  # * unpacks the range as elements of the list literal
```

Answer (score 0):

Change x like this;

```
x = list(range(1,11))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first case is a list with only one element: a sublist with the numbers 1-10

```
 x = [list(range(1,11))]
```

Thus the min and max can only be the one element...

Answer (score 0):

It happens because in your first statement, you're creating a list inside another list. Modify the first statement to `x = list(range(1,11))`, by using the keyword list you're already telling your code that variable should be a list once, so no need for the brackets.